# Hide every TD that's not the first TD of the TR.

Tags: jquery, html

http://jsfiddle.net/Z7r5z/1/

I'm trying to hide every TD within each TR that isn't the first TD. You can see a few of my attempts, but I'm not having luck with this.

`$(document).ready(function () {
    $("tr").each(function () {
        $("td").not(":first").hide();
        //$(this).next('td:second').hide();
        //$(this).next('td').not(":first").hide();
    })
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

To hide 1st `td` only

```
$("tr").find('td:eq(0)').hide();
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/9UZHq/)</kbd>

---

[.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

[:eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) --> starts from `0` index

---

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/9UZHq/1)</kbd>

Hide all `td` except `first td`

```
$("tr").find('td:not(:eq(0))').hide();
```

Comment: That *isn't* the first TD

Comment: Had to change this to (1) but it works now `$("tr").find('td:eq(1)').hide();`

Comment: That would only hide the second TD ?

Comment: OP should rewrite question if they want to hide the first TD, as the current way in which it is written says hiding all but first.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("td:nth-child(n+2)").hide()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `:first`, use [`:first-of-type`](http://api.jquery.com/first-of-type-selector/):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("tr").each(function () { 
     $("td").not(":first-of-type").hide();
  })
});
```

Alternatively, you could do this with pure CSS (unless you have a special reason to use jQuery for this):

```
.table td:not(:first-of-type) { display: none }
```